# Boot Ubuntu or Win 10 on Dell Machine without Using System Config

Tags: dual-boot

I recently bought a Dell Tower Windows 10 machine and installed Ubundu on an unused partition.
However, to switch between OS's, I have to hit F2 when booting to choose either "UEFI" to run Windows or "Legacy" (GRUB) to run Ubuntu.

The Ubuntu GRUB startup menu presents 5 choices: Ubuntu, Advanced Options for Ubuntu, Memory Test, Memory Test with serial port, and "MS-DOS 5.x/6.x/Win 3.1 on (/dev/sda5)"
I think the last choice should be to boot Windows 10, but I don't know how either to change the 5th choice or add a 6th choice for Windows 10.

Comment: you need to reinstall ubuntu in EFI mode

Comment: @ravery Can you post a full answer or provide a link if there already is an answer? Not knowing any better I would have tried [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Comment: I have no idea how to reinstall in "EFI" mode.  No such choice was presented by Ubuntu when I installed it.

Comment: the installer installs the ubuntu in the same mode that it booted it does not give a selection. see the given answer for how to force EFI boot.

Comment: If your Windows 10 is an upgrade from Windows 7, then you may have BIOS/MBR configuration for Windows. Grub would not be showing any entry for Windows if not in same Boot mode. Or do you have both an old BIOS Windows & new UEFI Windows 10? May be best to see details, you can run from your Ubuntu live installer or any working install, use ppa version not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: @oldfred -- in his question he clearly states that Windows is in EFI mode and Ubuntu is in Legacy mode

Comment: Sorry, but users are not always correct. I like to see the report or details to really know.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you have to use the Firmware boot selection is because Grub can not switch modes on the fly. Since you installed Grub in Legacy mode, it can not launch Windows in EFI mode. Thus you need to reinstall Ubuntu in EFI mode.

In the system settings turn off Legacy support to force the Installer to boot in EFI mode. I am also assuming you had to add a gurb bios partition since Win10 EFI requires GPT partitioning. This partition can be deleted since grub EFI does not need it.

Comment: There is no "EFI" boot option, only "UEFI".   If I turn off Legasy by choosing UEFI, the machine boots Windows 10 only.  If I turn on UEFI but disable the UEFI choice of Windows, the machine does not boot at all.

Comment: they are the same: UEFI is EFI

Comment: It appears that I can not set up a dual boot except by booting Ubuntu with a dual choice -- how to do this was my original question.  Can anyone tell me how to edit the Ubuntu menu?  It gives choices for changing the text of the last option (above).

Comment: you can not; Grub in legacy mode can not launch windows in EFI mode. You have to reinstall Ubuntu in UEFI mode to get a dual boot.

Comment: Nevertheless, can anyone tell me how to edit the Ubundu boot menu; the automatic edit worked fine for me in Windows 7 vs Fedora linux, in the machine I am now using online.  I just installed Fedora, and the dual boot worked.

Comment: I can't install Ubuntu any differently from the way I already did; I would try this if I could change something.   This is why I would like to try editting the Ubuntu boot menu.

Comment: you have the 64 bit Ubuntu yes? turn off legacy support and boot the installer

Comment: To clarify:  The Ubuntu boot DVD will not load unless I am in a legacy mode of Windows 10.

Comment: OK!  Wait:  I have always inserted the Ubuntu DVD after running setup.   I just inserted it BEFORE starting the machine, and I now have a choice to reinstall in UEFI mode.   Thank you for the advice:  I will try a nonlegacy install and will update this forum with the result.

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED!  I now get an Ubuntu boot menu which allows me either to run Windows or Ubuntu.